# How would you retrieve specific error codes from an oracle database programmatically?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Scenario:
I wish to define a constant for the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX error code:

```
GCN_DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX        CONSTANT NUMBER := -1;
```

However, I would like to set the value programmatically:

```
GCN_DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX        CONSTANT NUMBER := DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX.ERRCODE;
```

Is there a way to do this w/out creating a custom function like this?:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DUP_VAL_ERR_CODE
RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
   raise dup_val_on_index;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN SQLCODE;
END;
/
```

Comment: what for? it's more common to do the very opposite things - define constant exceptions for error codes...

Comment: We are bulk collecting the erorrs during a forall loop, then doing logging for each exception. We use the error code to determine what to do next.

Comment: @scrappythenell, a `forall` will raise a single error for the entire data-set rather than a single record in that data-set. What happens if you want to do something else for only a single record? Is such a situation possible?

Comment: @Ben, it will not. Check out `save exceptions` clause )

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

Check out `SYS.STANDARD` package - it's the place where all the exceptions, SQL functions, and  everything else "predefined" is actually defined.

Pretty much straightforward:

```
DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception;
    pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX, '-0001');
```